# Not able to populate the User object when using Spring OAuth2 Jdbc token store

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I updated Roy Clarkson's Spring REST service (https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth) with a Jdbc-based token store. The original implementation uses an in-memory token store. I was able to see the user details in the User object. On the other hand, after switching to Jdbc-based token store, all the fields in the User object were empty. It appears somehow Spring security was not able to associate the access token with the user under which I obtained the token when I was using Jdbc-based token store.

**The in-memory token store implementation:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
        return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
        return tokenServices;
    }
}
```

**The REST endpoint:**

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, user.getName()));
}
```

user.getName() returns the name of the user under which I obtained the access token.

**The jdbc token store implementation:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
        return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
        return tokenServices;
    }
}
```

**The REST endpoint:**

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, user.getName()));
}
```

user.getName() returns null.

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByLogin(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
        }
        return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return getRoles();
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return getLogin();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String privilege;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
        super();
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.name = user.getName();
        this.login = user.getLogin();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
        this.privilege = user.getPrivilege();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPrivilege() {return privilege; }

    public void setPrivilege(String privilege) {this.privilege = privilege; }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the implementation of `CustomUserDetailsService` (which you haven't shown)?

Comment: Hi @DaveSyer, I updated the post to include the 'CustomUserDetailsService' and 'User' implementation. 'user.getName()' will return the _name_ stored in the _User_table. I do not know why it can only read the value when I use the in memory token store.

Comment: I don't know either, but `@Autowired` of a field that is defined as a `@Bean` in the same class is asking for trouble so I suggest you don't do that to start with.

Comment: +1 encountering exactly same issue. Switched from in-memory tokenStore to jdbcTokenStore and got same issue.

Comment: Debugged though whole spring filters and found out that while saving "authentication" blob Principal had userDetail values. But while reading back it comes out to be null.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the "UserRepositoryUserDetails" you are creating is not serializable.

UserRepositoryUserDetails is implementing "UserDetails" which is Serializable but the class it is extending "User" is not Serializable.

You must be getting a warning also from comiler to add a serialId.

**Solution**

*Make your UserRepositoryUserDetails as serializable.*

Answer (score 1):

After making **User class serializable** everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. This helped me a lot